# How can I create array elements dynamically and assign values (from variable with the same names) to the elements

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create elements of an array dynamically and need to assign values to each array element (with the same names) and push the item to the array.  I don't know how to achieve this.  Please take a look at my code which I attached below.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  thanks.

I would like to have all elements of the array with a number value, not Lenght0, Lenght1......
The reason why I declare all the variables Length0, Length1..... and assign values to them is for testing purpose. In my application, the values are available on the screen and the script suppose to read in the values from these fields and add them to the array, then do some calculations with these values.

```
let Length0 = 188;
let Length1 = 54;
let Length2 = 54;
let Length3 = 312;
let Length4 = 54;
let Length5 = 54;
let Length6 = 976;
let Length7 = 54;
let Length8 = 54;
let Length9 = 169;
let Length10 = 54;
let Length11 = 54;
let Length12 = 130;
let Length13 = 57;
let Length14 = 54;
let Length15 = 260;
let Length16 = 54;

let numberOfAxles = 12;
let lengthString = '';
let Lengths = [];

let Lengths =[Length0,Length1,Length2,Length3,Length4,Length5,Length6,Length7,Length8,Length9,Length10,Length11];

document.write(Lengths+'<br><br>');

for (let i = 0; i < numberOfAxles; i++) {
    lengthString = 'Length' + i;
    Lengths.push('Length' + i);
    //document.write(Lengths +' <br><br>');
}

//document.write('Length String: ' + lengthString + '<br>');
document.write('<br>Second: ' + Lengths + '<br>');
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure I get why you want to do this, but i think this is what you are looking for:

```js
let Length0 = 188;
let Length1 = 54;
let Length2 = 54;
let Length3 = 312;
let Length4 = 54;
let Length5 = 54;
let Length6 = 976;
let Length7 = 54;
let Length8 = 54;
let Length9 = 169;
let Length10 = 54;
let Length11 = 54;
let Length12 = 130;
let Length13 = 57;
let Length14 = 54;
let Length15 = 260;
let Length16 = 54;

let numberOfAxles = 12;
let Lengths = [];

for (let i = 0; i < numberOfAxles; i++) {
    Lengths.push(eval('Length' + i));
}
console.log(Lengths);

document.write('Second: ' + Lengths.join(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need all those Length*N* variables. You can directly build up an array that contains numbers:

```
let lengths = [188, 54, 54, /*...*/];
```

Then to access a value at a certain location in the array, do

```
lengths[1] // the second element, 54
```

or using a variable to index:

```
let i = 0;
lengths[i]; // 188
```

---

Sidenotes:

- `let` is just as `var`, just better, so just use that instead.
- You can use the `.length` property to get the number of elements in an array, e.g. `lengths.length`, there is no need for `numberOfAxles`.

Comment: Hi Jonas, thank you for your help on this.  However, in my situation, users will enter values on a screen.  I need to graph these values and add them to the array.  Therefore, I am trying to replicate the scenario by creating the variables instead of creating an array with pre-filled values.  just for a test I did var Lengths =[Length0,Length1,Length2,Length3,Length4,Length5,Length6,Length7,Length8,Length9,Length10,Length11]; and the values get added to the array.  However, the for loop did not work.  It just added text values (Length0, Length1...) to the array.

Comment: "I'm trying to replicate the scenario" ... that makes even less sense. Why not just `lengths.push( +prompt("number?") )` ?

Comment: can you post the html code? on what event are you capturing the user input?

Comment: Jonas, I have to use axleNumbers because it is a required field on the screen where users enter a number for how many axles the involved vehicle has.  therefore, I can't use array.length.  on the same form, where users will enter values for Lengths0 to Lengths(n), so there is not really a prompt.  on submit the script will run, grab the length values and axles number to calculate weight.  my working sample of what I am trying to do here:  https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G7Q4UDG6PHQY  what I am looking for is a way to read in length values on the screen dynamically.  Thanks